# O que seria "Assinatura do Servidor" e como desligá-la?

Tags: apache, http, servidor, iis, nginx

Em alguns testes constatou que a "assinatura do servidor estava ligada", eu não sei o que é isso. O que é e como posso desligar essa "assinatura"? Em testes de segurança realizados recomendam que eu desligue essa assinatura pra preservar a segurança do servidor.

Comment: Informe qual o sistema operacional e o servidor web que está utilizando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É a informação que o servidor HTTP fornece em algumas circunstâncias como páginas de erro e *headers*. Isto não é tão crítico assim, apenas fornece informações úteis para *hackers*.

Você deve adicionar:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

ao seu arquivo de configuração, provavelmente `httpd.conf` (alguns sistemas usam `apache2.conf`).

Precisa recarregar o arquivo ou reiniciar o servidor.

Você pode ver o antes e depois tentando acessar uma página inexistente.

Embora raro e provavelmente não será problema seu, isto pode causar alguns efeitos colaterais indesejáveis quando algum software precisa destas informações para tomar decisões.

[Documentação](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serversignature).